# Load serialport module in browser using browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

Iam trying to use serialport nodejs module in a browser, i use browserify but iam getting TypeError: Error.captureStackTrace is not a function, the error is comming from bundle.js file created by browserify. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In Node, the `Error.captureStackTrace` is a function:

```
> typeof Error.captureStackTrace
'function'
```

In the browser it may also be the case:

```
typeof Error.captureStackTrace
"function"
```

but this is not standard, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

But in any case you will not be able to access serial ports in the browser because the browser will not let you access the hardware directly, unlike Node that is just a normal userspace process. This is unrelated to the `Error` object's methods or the module used. It's just a security model of the browser.